# Pinia firebase user emailVerified property loses reactivity

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

Currently I'm building an app that on user signup navigates the user to an *email verification page*. This page then watches the firebase user object inside of a Pinia store waiting for the emailVerified user property to update before directing them to a new page.

When I update the user object manually using vue devtools I can observe my console.log. When I receive the email verification email and use the link provided by firebase my watcher does not react to the user update. I can refresh the pinia store using my vue devtools and I see emailVerified inside my firebase user object has been updated to true but my watcher was never hit.

Any ideas on why I am losing reactivity when going through the email flow?

**testStore.js**

```
export const useTestStore = defineStore('test', () => {
   const auth = getAuth()
  const {user} = useAuth(auth)

  return {
    user: user,
  }
})
```

**emailVerification.js**

```
<script setup>
const { user } = storeToRefs(testStore)

watch(user, () => {
  console.log('Direct user to new page')
}, { deep:true })
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try to use useCurrentUser directly? You're trying to debug with unnecessary moving parts, although I don't see the problem with the store itself.

Comment: Same thing is observed when using useCurrentUser directly

Comment: Then your problem is solely with vuefire, probably itself and not Firebase in general. This could be expected since it's unstable

Comment: Ive removed vuefire and replaced it with vueuse and am still observing the same results.

Comment: You need to be very aware of the actual implementation. The problem is based on how specific low profile libs are implemented. I can see that " It provides a reactive user and isAuthenticated so you can easily react to changes in the users' authentication status", and this is what really happens https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/blob/main/packages/firebase/useAuth/index.ts . You can create your own composable if you're after specific behaviour

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when replacing my watcher with setInterval it seems to works... although this is not the ideal solution

```
setInterval(function () {
      if(user){
        if(user.value?.emailVerified) {
          console.log('Direct user to new page');
        }
      }
}, 5000);
```